# getPlayWhenReady with ExoPlayer doesn't work

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to save the current position and current player state of exoplayer
so the current position is work fine when I rotate the screen the video start from where I reach to
but I want to save the state of player so when the player is start and I rotate the screen the player should keep stating and vise verse when the player is paused and I rotate the screen I want the player keep paused too

so this is the code that I tried:

```
boolean getPlayerWhenReady ;

    private long exo_current_position = 0;
    private boolean playerStopped = false;
    private long playerStopPosition;
    private static final String EXO_CURRENT_POSITION = "current_position";

    private void initializePlayer(Uri mediaUri) {
            if (player == null) {
                TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveVideoTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
                DefaultTrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(handler, videoTrackSelectionFactory);
                LoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl();

                player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(getContext(), trackSelector, loadControl);
                exoPlayer.setPlayer(player);

                String userAgent = Util.getUserAgent(getContext(), "Baking App");
                MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(mediaUri, new DefaultDataSourceFactory(getContext(), userAgent), new DefaultExtractorsFactory(), null, null);
                player.prepare(mediaSource);
                if (exo_current_position != 0 && !playerStopped){
                    player.seekTo(exo_current_position);
                }
                else {
                    player.seekTo(playerStopPosition);
                }
                player.setPlayWhenReady(getPlayerWhenReady);
            }
        }

    @Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle currentState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(currentState);
            currentState.putParcelableArrayList("Steps",steps);
            currentState.putInt("Step",selectedIndex);
            currentState.putLong(EXO_CURRENT_POSITION,player.getCurrentPosition());
            getPlayerWhenReady = player.getPlayWhenReady();
            currentState.putBoolean("state", getPlayerWhenReady);
        }

        public boolean isInLandscapeMode( Context context ) {
            return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDetach() {
            super.onDetach();
            if (player!=null) {
                player.stop();
                player.release();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyView() {
            super.onDestroyView();
            if (player!=null) {
                player.stop();
                player.release();
                player=null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            if (player!=null) {
                player.stop();
                playerStopPosition = player.getCurrentPosition();
                playerStopped = true;
                player.release();
                getPlayerWhenReady = player.getPlayWhenReady();
                player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            if (player!=null) {
                player.stop();
                player.release();
                getPlayerWhenReady = player.getPlayWhenReady();
                player.setPlayWhenReady(getPlayerWhenReady);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            if (player!=null) {
                getPlayerWhenReady = player.getPlayWhenReady();
                player.setPlayWhenReady(getPlayerWhenReady);
            }
        }

    }
```

as you can see I use the getPlayWhenReady to save the state of player but it doesn't work when the player is playing and I rotate the screen it paused and when the player is paused and I rotate the screen it just keep paused

thanks I solve the problem by use the:

```
if(savedInstanceState != null) {
            getPlayerWhenReady = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("state");
        }
```